# Define global constant with mezzio swoole/openswoole

Tags: php, mezzio, swoole, openswoole

im trying to set a global constant that would be accessible to all php swoole processes and threads later, but it seems to be not visible or something

Here's my index.php - almost vanilla mezzio - I only see **APPROOT** constant:

```
(function () {
    if (!defined('APPROOT')) {
        define('APPROOT', __DIR__);
    }

    /** @var \Psr\Container\ContainerInterface $container */
    $container = require 'config/container.php';

    /** @var \Mezzio\Application $app */
    $app     = $container->get(\Mezzio\Application::class);
    $factory = $container->get(\Mezzio\MiddlewareFactory::class);

    // Execute programmatic/declarative middleware pipeline and routing
    // configuration statements
    (require 'config/pipeline.php')($app, $factory, $container);
    (require 'config/routes.php')($app, $factory, $container);

    $app->run();
})();
```

But then I get an error when I try to reference/use that constant in one of the middlewares:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Application\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;

class BootstrapMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    public function __construct(private ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory)
    {
    }

    public function process(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        RequestHandlerInterface $handler
    ): ResponseInterface {


        $this->setAssetsCompiledLoc();

        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        return $response;
    }

    private function setAssetsCompiledLoc()
    {
        if ( ! defined('ASSET_MAP')) {
            $manifestPath = \APPROOT . '/manifests/manifest-' . ENV . '.json';
            // ...blah...
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error Undefined constant "APPROOT"

Why? Is that because all variable outside of the swoole context are discarded and I set this outside of swoole context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reviewing source code for Mezzio\Swoole\Command\StartCommand I've discovered that index.php that I thought was an entry point to my php swoole application is actually not being used at all.
thus constants were indeed undefined.